# How to add hyphens inside 32 alpha numeric strings

Tags: c++, string

My program randomly generates 32 alpha numeric strings and **I want to add hyphens between the characters exactly like this format 56C13783-RR1B-1B66-7685-83C9343667AE.** My code before trying to add changes was previously in this format EA25D82041974B9089459223D74E84DA.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>     /* srand, rand */
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

string RandomString(int len)
{
    string str = "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef";
    string newstr;
    int pos;
    while(newstr.size() != len) {
        pos = ((rand() % (str.size() - 1)));
        newstr += str.substr(pos, 1);
    }
    return newstr;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int user_input;
    int hyphens[4] = { 9, 14, 19, 24 };

    cout << "Enter how many codes you want: ";
    cin >> user_input;
    for (int i = 0; i < user_input; i++)
    {
        string random_str = RandomString(32);
        cout << "random_str: " << random_str << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < random_str.length(); ++i) {
            if (random_str[i] == hyphens) { 
                random_str[i] = '-';
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

`main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:35:30: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] if (random_str[i] == hyphens) {`

This was the error I got when trying to compile my code.

Comment: `random_str` is of type `std::string`. `random_str[i]` returns a `char&` or `const char&`. `hyphens` is of type `int[4]`. There are not many operators which accept a C array but in most cases the array decays to a pointer. I.e. `hyphens` is converted to `int*`. For `random_str[i] == hyphens`, the `const char&` is converted to an `int`. (That's for most operations that smaller integral types like `char` and `short` are converted to `int` as there are no corresponding operators for the former.) So, `random_str[i] == hyphens` results in comparison of `int` with `int*` which isn't allowed.

Comment: Isn't it the case that you want to compare `i` with every element of `hyphens`? And, why the `for` loop over `random_str`? Wouldn't it make more sense to iterate over `hyphens` to assign the hyphen to each resp. indexed element of the `string`?

Comment: I used the `for` loop over `random_str` because it allows the user to pick how many times he/she can iterate the string. If the user wants 5 codes, then he/she just has to input 5 and will receive 5 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my question with a few steps using int counter and replacing the faulty version of the hyphens code with a corrected version of it. It puts hyphens in the correct spots where I want it placed. This was the simplest one I could think of, but I'm sure you can create better ones for it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> /* srand, rand */
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

string RandomString(int len)
{
  string str = "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef";
  string newstr;
  int pos;
  while (newstr.size() != len)
  {
    pos = ((rand() % (str.size() - 1)));
    newstr += str.substr(pos, 1);
  }
  return newstr;
}

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int user_input;
  int hyphens[4] = {9, 14, 19, 24};

  cout << "Enter how many codes you want: ";
  cin >> user_input;
  for (int i = 0; i < user_input; i++)
  {
    string random_str = RandomString(32);
    //cout << "random_str: " << random_str << endl;

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < random_str.length(); ++i)
    {

      if (i == hyphens[counter])
      {
        random_str.insert(hyphens[counter], "-");
        counter++;
      }
    }
    cout << random_str << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```